# Cambio automático de enlaces de páginas

Tags: php, html

Me explico...

No se si se puede hacer o no, por eso hablo desde el desconocimiento.

Tengo una web de trabajo temporal.
Esta web tiene un enlace de "Inscripción" para que nuevas empresas se registren y comiencen a publicar sus ofertas.
Generalmente, esta deshabilitado y al darle a "Inscripción" aparece que no hay plazo de inscripción abierto.
Durante una semana o dos al año abrimos ese periodo de inscripción para las empresas y luego volvemos a cerrar la inscripción.

En cuanto a la parte técnica, cuando esta cerrado el enlace redirige a la pagina "inscripcioncerrada.php" y cuando nos establecen el periodo para abrir la inscripción lo que hacemos es cambiar la redirección a "inscripcionabierta.php". Cuando se cierra hacemos a la inversa, cambiamos "inscripcionabierta.php" por "inscripcioncerrada.php".

Esto realmente es tedioso y bastante largo ya que tenemos muchas paginas donde se hace referencia al enlace "Inscripción" y hay que cambiarlo cada vez que se abre o cierra la inscripcion en unas 20 páginas individualmente.

Por eso, pregunto (como he dicho bajo el desconocimiento) si existe alguna manera de hacer una funcion o script que cuando quiera abrir el periodo de inscripcion me cambie los enlaces de las 20 paginas que quiero a "inscripcionabierta.php".
Esto seria mucho mas rapido y eficiente para mi.

P.D: La web esta hecha en PHP como podeis ver por las extensiones.

P.D2: Las fechas de inscripcion cambian todos los años, es decir, no se abre y se cierra el periodo de inscripción el mismo dia todos los año.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: En vez de poner las rutas "a mano" usa una variable con la ruta.

Comment: Explicate. $inscripcioncerrada = "inscripcioncerrada.php" y $inscripcionabierta = "inscripcionabierta.php" Pero como las uso? Tengo que cambiarlo en las 20 paginas igualmente...

Comment: No sé si es la mejor implementación pero lo primero que me viene a la cabeza es una variable de sesión $_SESSION['estadoInscripciones'] o como quieras llamarla que tendrá $_SESSION['estadoInscripciones'] = "inscripcionabierta.php" o $_SESSION['estadoInscripciones'] = "inscripcioncerrada.php".

Comment: Entiendo por donde vas... El problema es que tengo index.php, y otras paginas que tienen <a href="inscripcioncerrada.php"...> y no se como poder hacerlo lo que tu dices, seguiria teniendo que repetir

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['estadoInscripciones'] ?>">

Comment: si, pero donde declaro $_SESSION['estadoInscripciones'] o donde le doy las opciones de valor a escoger?

Comment: Ahí está la cosa, necesitas guardar el estado. Puedes metar un campo en el que guardar la ruta en la BD y al entrar en la página coges de la BD el valor y lo metes en la variable.

Comment: Al entrar en que pagina? Si lo pongo en el index.php y al ser $_SESSION me lo mantiene?

Comment: Ejemplos que puedes probar para ver si te convence: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp Y la documentación oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: me puede valer para cambiarlo una unica vez en vez de las 20 paginas. eso de la BD como lo plantearias?

Comment: ¿No tienes ya una BD para la página?

Comment: si, pero lo que dices no lo visualizo ya que tendria que modificar tambien

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77230/discussion-between-asier-2-and-paolo-frigenti).

Comment: Has probado a crear una página llamada inscripciones.php y sea esa la que redirige?. Es una opción rápida. Otra opción sería una variable que se modifique cuando  quieras y si tienes un backend igual lo podrías confiugrar apoyada en una base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**inscripciones.php**

```
$enlaceInscripcion = 'inscripcionabierta.php'
```

En TODOS los ficheros php que tengas enlaces a esa url, al inicio, cargas un

```
include_once("ruta/hasta/el/fichero/inscripciones.php");
```

(o incluso mejor, si ya tienes un fichero "header" o similar que ya cargas con include o require en todas las páginas, puedes definir ahí mismo la variable)

con esto tienes en TODOS los ficheros, definida una variable llamada $enlaceInscripcion que vale lo que le pongas tú en el fichero "inscripciones.php".

Ahora modificas en TODAS las páginas el enlace que tenías a "inscripcionabierta.php" o "inscripcioncerrada.php" y lo sustituyes por

```
<?= $enlaceInscripcion; ?>
```

de modo que según cambies el contenido en el fichero del include, automáticamente en todos los enlaces pondrá la url que quieres.

Esto lo haces una vez, y ya está, a partir de ahí solo necesitas cambiar el contenido del "inscripciones.php" para llevar al visitante donde necesites, en vez de cambiar a mano los 20 enlaces.